# Document approved without major version?

Tags: 2007, workflow

We are using MOSS 2007. We have SharePoint set up to publish on major versions.

One of my users pointed out that their document was approved but nobody could see it. I went in and this is what I saw:

Won't allow me to post pictures... Here is the link. 
"http://i90.photobucket.com/albums/k274/ZeroHero2/SharePoint.png"

If you do not wish to follow the link here is a basic example:

```
Type | Name | Title | some  more headers | Version | Approval Status | Approval WorkFlow 

word | 003  | title | stuff              | 0.13    | Pending         | Approved
word | 004  | title | stuff              | 0.13    | Pending         | Approved
```

As you can see there is no major version published, however a full workflow was somehow completed and there is no Major version. I tried to replicate the above but I can't seem to. I already know how to fix the version and the approval; however I am trying to find a cause so this will not happen again.

Few other details:

- The workflows where done in SharePoint (OOTB).
- I am not a SharePoint developer nor do we have one. We have no custom pages.
- I know enough about SharePoint for it to be dangerous. So bare with me. :)

Any ideas, questions, flaming would be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your screenshot...it looks like the Approval Workflow has the status of Approved, but the approval status of Pending.  Perhaps if you take a look at the workflow history, you can determine is a workflow completed successfully, or is an error state?  Other than that, perhaps check the ULS logs to see if anything strange is going on?